# Display roll up progress bar as custom field for a work item in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, rollup, tfs-workitem

I am a little new to azure devops. Is it possible to display a roll up progress bar as a field in a work item in azure devops? I am interested in the just the actual value and not the bar

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no build-in feature to achieve your goal, you could refer to this official doc for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/display-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process

Rollup columns allow you to view progress bars or totals of numeric fields for descendant items within a hierarchy. But there's no such field to be listed within the work item view.

You could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion